# Get Keys of MongoMapper Model

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

Suppose the following model:

```
class Article
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :body, String
end
```

Could I get the keys of the model into an array or hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Article.keys` will give you a hash of key names to key objects.  If you just want the key names, try `Article.keys.keys`.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :011 > Article.keys
 => { 
  "_id"  => #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Keys::Key:0x000001041e5d48 @type=ObjectId, @name="_id", @options={}, @default_value=nil>,
  "name" => #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Keys::Key:0x00000104013100 @type=String, @name="name", @options={}, @default_value=nil>,
  "body" => #<MongoMapper::Plugins::Keys::Key:0x00000104011b20 @type=String, @name="body", @options={}, @default_value=nil>
}
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :012 > Article.keys.keys
 => ["_id", "name", "body"]
```

Watch out though, if you dynamically set any keys that aren't declared in your model, or you load an object that has extra keys that aren't in your model, they will show up in the keys hash.  See https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/195.

Comment: Argh, the unexpected dynamic loading of keys from an object frustrated us for hours! Is there a way to reset MM back to what's defined in the model?

Comment: Crashalot: no supported way, but that keys hash explained above is what MM uses if you wanted to try to hot-fix it.  However, if you just unset the key and restart your app, everything should be fine and you shouldn't have to hot-fix the app (as advised on the MM mailing list).